# How to cope with Windows 8-10 Start Screen icon dragging Rubik's Cube?

Tags: windows, windows-8, icons, start-screen

The Windows "Start Screen" introduced in Windows 8 and still present in Windows 10 shows large icons for programs arranged in a matrix:

[image: Start Screen]

I find the movement logic in the interface to be completely illogical. For example, if I drag an icon from one place to another, it does not just switch the two icons in question. Entire rows and columns change position. I have no idea how to predict what the outcome of a particular drag is, so my icons are perpetually disorganized.

Is there some secret to understanding the logic behind this Rubik's Cube interface? How can I control the movements so I can get the icons where I want them?

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows 8: Text

There's a fair bit of auto-alignment, but it's easy to understand:

- The screen scrolls horizontally, and is separated by whitespace into vertical groups. You can set a title for each group, and move the whole group as a single unit (using the "zoom out" corner button). Groups do not interact with each other.
- Within each group, tiles form invisible columns as wide as two "normal" tiles. (You can see the columns slightly separate *while* dragging a tile. The big area in your example is 3 columns.)
- Medium and wide tiles within the group are arranged linearly – rows go from left to right until they fill the column, then wrap to the next row. Eventually they reach the bottom of the screen and start a new column. **Basically, tiles flow like columnated text.**
- When you drag a tile, you *insert* it in between two existing tiles, shifting some tiles to the right. (The last tile overflows to the next row, and from the last row to the next column. Again, similar to dragging & dropping words in Notepad.)
- Small tiles are arranged as a 4-pack *within* the space of a medium tile – going left to right, wrapping to the next 'small' row, and overflowing to the next 'medium' area when full. 
   (When you insert a medium or large tile, it shifts the whole 4-pack as a single unit.)
- However, small tiles don't automatically flow *backwards* to fill empty space in the previous medium area. So if you mainly use small tiles, it's possible to have several adjacent half-full areas. (The same is not true for regular sizes – medium/large tiles *do* flow backwards to the previous column.)

#### Windows 10: Grid

Everything is much simpler:

- The screen scrolls vertically, and is divided into 2–3 main columns. Each column has fixed width (3 medium tiles), expands downwards, and has several horizontally-separated groups.
- Each group can still have a title, and be moved between columns (using the ══ grip).
- Tiles are positioned on a grid. They no longer flow automatically – inserting will not reflow, but merely *shift* other tiles either to the side (but only if there is space) or downwards.
- The grid is aligned to the size of a 'small' tile, so small tiles no longer reserve a full medium space. (Now it's the opposite: medium tiles use a 2x2 area.)
- Fully empty horizontal spaces automatically collapse. (Trying to horizontally separate tiles will result in a new group.)

Comment: I find this "explanation" to be confusing and after reading it, I am no closer to understanding how to arrange the icons the way I want them. What I want to do is put icons where I want them in the matrix and this does not explain how to do that. I am using Windows 10.